# Regular expression for barcodes (12 or 14 digits)

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regular expression which will match barcode.  The barcodes can be 12 or 14 digits long (never 13) and the first digit has to be `8`.  Examples:

```
800909887898  
80903243234323
```

I've got something like this: `^[8]{1}[0-9]{11}$` but I don't know hot to recognize last 2 digits. It's can be 2 digits character or null (the expression `[0-9]{0-2}` will not work fine because quantifier don't work like OR).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this one

```
^8[0-9]{11}([0-9]{2})?$
```

[0-9]{2} means two digits

(...)? means zero or one time

Comment: You should probably put a `?:` inside the parentheses, since we probably don't need to capture the last two digits.

Answer (score 2):

So, if you want something that starts with 8 and can be exactly 12 or 14 digits, then you can use `|` for an "or" in the regex:

`^8\d{11}$|^8\d{13}$`

Comment: `^(8\d{11}|8\d{13})$` otherwise it will match `^8\d{11}` or `8\d{13}$`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that...that's why I edited in the `$` before the `|` and the `^` after the `|`.  Of course, your way works, but unless you wanna capture the match, you'll probably want a `?:`, as in `^(?:8\d{11}|8\d{13})$`.